# Copied python egg no longer works

Tags: python

I needed to make a change to a 3rd party library, so I edited the files in the egg (which is not zipped). The egg lives in site-packages in a virtualenv. Everything works fine on my dev machine, but when I copied the egg to another machine, the module can longer be found to import.

I'm sure I went about this the wrong way, but I'm hoping there's a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix to your problem should be by adding the full path of the egg to a .pth file which should exist in the sys-path (in your case site-packages).

Comment: Ugh...I did initially update the easy_install.pth file, and when I went back to look, I had made a typo. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction!